# ogrinfo: Get a sample row from a GeoJSON file?

Tags: geojson, ogr2ogr, ogrinfo

I know how to examine the properties of a GeoJSON file:

```
ogrinfo my.geojson OGRGeoJSON -so
```

But is there a way that I can retrieve a single feature's actual properties, to see what they look like?

I guess I can do this with `head`, but it would be nice if there was a structured way.

Comment: You should consider accepting some answers on this site occasionally. It helps keep the site clean, but also, in the case of some of your unaccepted questions, a great deal of work has gone into the answers. I would suggest that if for some reason the answer isn't what you expected, you clarify the  question. 7 unaccepted answers in a row strikes me as excessive, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure! Check the [documentation](http://www.gdal.org/ogrinfo.html) for multiple options. Here are some I thought of.

Getting the first feature:

```
ogrinfo -al -fid 1 file.geojson
```

Getting the first feature via SQL:

```
ogrinfo -al -sql "SELECT * FROM OGRGeoJSON WHERE fid=1" file.geojson
```

On GDAL 2.2 you could use LIMIT like this:

```
ogrinfo -al -sql "SELECT * FROM OGRGeoJSON LIMIT 1" file.geojson
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is the resulting 'Layer name' is 'SELECT'?